# wsl2, gdb and cross-debug 32bit i386 - failing to map addresses to symbols ( in ?? () )

Tags: c++, gdb, cross-compiling, qemu, wsl-2

I'm having issues when trying to debug a cross compiled binary on my WSL2 host and only end up with backtraces with addresses in ?? (), any hint's on what to verify and change are welcome!

`file mybin` shows:

> ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=..., with debug_info, not stripped

The application is started in WSL2 via qemu-i386(based on output from ps)
NOTE: I was wondering a bit about this because in my prev dev env using vm-ware and ubuntu 18.04 i was not seeing qemu-i386 used but did not think more about it based on WSL2 issues regarding 32bit application support referring to qemu and binfmt solving it.

I'm running gdb-multiarch (GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04) 9.2)

Loading the executable and listing symbols with `info functions <a_regex>` **works fine** but when attaching and breaking i get bt's like this (NOTE output below is taken from VSCode with a few logging flags enabled, hence the -exec bt thing for example):

```
-exec bt
1: (777701) <-1183-interpreter-exec console "bt"
1: (777704) ->~"#0 0x000000000047a4ea in ?? ()\n"
1: (777707) ->~"#1 0x00007ffd2dcdb1c0 in ?? ()\n"
1: (777709) ->~"#2 0x0000000000467efc in ?? ()\n"
1: (777711) ->~"#3 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()\n"
```

NOTE: When attaching i get the following warning:

> warning: Selected architecture i386 is not compatible with reported target architecture i386:x86-64

setting architecture to i386:x86-64 is accepted by gdb but makes no difference

Setting a breakpoint gives the following error:

```
1: (40020) ->&"Cannot insert breakpoint 1.\n" 
1: (40020) ->&"Cannot access memory at address 0xbce346f\n" 
1: (40020) ->&"\n" 
1: (40023) ->^error,msg="Command aborted."
```

**UPDATE: SOLVED**
Thought installing gcc-multilib solved it but it seems more likely the issue was because of a bug in Docker Desktop which has been fixed in v3.2.2. See description in my own answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The qemu-i386 thing was bugging me so I decided to try compiling a simple .c with -m32 flag to check if it also would trigger being run via qemu, got errors because I was missing gcc-multilib so I installed it.

Started the buildt binary and noticed that it did not run via qemu-i386.
Started my original application again and this time it did also not start via qemu.
Started gdb-multiarch, loaded the bin and attached to the process and now suddenly everything worked fine, got a nice proper backtrace!

Comment: After a restart qemu seems to be invoked again, both for the simple -m32 main.c test and the original application.

Comment: strace showed a readlink("/proc/self/exe", "/usr/bin/qemu-i386", 4096) = 18

searched and found an issue with recent Docker Desktop: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/10594

Disabled Docker Desktop and it started working again.

DD 3.2.2 says it has fixed the issue, will try it later